# How to create tableview that shows/hide cells when you click on section in swift?

Tags: swift, uitableview, uitableviewsectionheader

How to create a tableview that allows user to show / hide cells of particular section when you click on that particular section in swift ??

Comment: what you have done so far ?

Comment: can you elaborate a bit more your question?